# webscraping with R and rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a project where I should scrape a series of articles from news sites. I am interested in the headline and text of the news. In most cases, the site maintains a base URL, for example:

> **https://www.americanthinker.com**/articles/2019/11/why_rich_people_love_poor_immigrants.html
>   **https://tmp.americanthinker.com**/blog/2015/01/california_begins_giving_drivers_licenses_to_illegal_aliens.html

As there are a so many articles (more than 1000) to download, I thought of creating a function to download all data automatically. A vector would provide all web addresses (one per line):

```r
article 
[1] "https://www.americanthinker.com/articles/2019/11/why_rich_people_love_poor_immigrants.html"                   
[2] "https://tmp.americanthinker.com/blog/2015/01/california_begins_giving_drivers_licenses_to_illegal_aliens.html"
[3] "https://www.americanthinker.com/articles/2018/11/immigrants_will_not_fund_our_retirement.html"                
> str(article)
 chr [1:3] "https://www.americanthinker.com/articles/2019/11/why_rich_people_love_poor_immigrants.html" ...
> summary(article)
   Length     Class      Mode 
        3 character character
```

As a result, the script would use the vector as a source for the addresses and create a dataframe with the title and text of each article. But some errors pop up. Here are the codes I wrote, based on a series of Stack Overflow posts:

**Packages**

```r
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(xml2) 
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
```

**Importing CSV and exporting as a vector**

```r
base <- read_csv(file.choose(), col_names = FALSE)
article <- pull(base,X1)
```

**First try**

```r
articles_final <- map_df(article, function(i){
  pages<-read_html(article)
  title <-
    article %>%  map_chr(. %>% html_node("h1") %>% html_text())
  content <-
    article %>% map_chr(. %>% html_nodes('.article_body span') %>% html_text() %>% paste(., collapse = ""))
  article_table <- data.frame("Title" = title, "Content" = content)
  return(article_table)
})
```

**Second try**

```r
map_df(1:3, function(i){
  page <- read_html(sprintf(article,i))
  data.frame(Title = html_text(html_nodes(page,'.h1')),
             Content= html_text(html_nodes(page,'.article_body span')),
             Site = "American Thinker"
             )
}) -> articles_final
```

In both cases, I am getting the following error while running these functions:

```r
Error in doc_parse_file (con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options):
Expecting a single string value: 
[type = character; extent = 3].
```

I need this to download and analyse articles

Thank you very much for your help.

**edit**

I tried the code suggested bellow:

```r
I tried and it dod not work, some problem with my coding:
> map_dfc(.x = article,
+         .f = function(x){
+           foo <- tibble(Title = read_html(x) %>%
+                           html_nodes("h1") %>% 
+                           html_text() %>%
+                           .[nchar(.) > 0],
+                         Content = read_html(x) %>% 
+                           html_nodes("p") %>% 
+                           html_text(),
+                         Site = "AmericanThinker")%>%
+             filter(nchar(Content) > 0)
+           }
+         ) -> out
Error: Argument 3 must be length 28, not 46
```

But as you see a new error pops up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I tried for you. I was playing with Selector Gadget and checking page source. After some inspection, I think you need to use `<title>` and `<div class="article_body">`. The `map()` part is looping through the three articles in `article` and creating a data frame. Each row represents each article. I think you still need to do some string manipulation to have clean text. But this will help you to scrape the contents you need.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

article <- c("https://www.americanthinker.com/articles/2019/11/why_rich_people_love_poor_immigrants.html",
         "https://tmp.americanthinker.com/blog/2015/01/california_begins_giving_drivers_licenses_to_illegal_aliens.html",
         "https://www.americanthinker.com/articles/2018/11/immigrants_will_not_fund_our_retirement.html")

 map_dfr(.x = article,
         .f = function(x){

                 tibble(Title = read_html(x) %>%
                                html_nodes("title") %>%
                                html_text(),
                        Content = read_html(x) %>%
                                  html_nodes(xpath = "//div[@class='article_body']") %>%
                                  html_text(),
                        Site = "AmericanThinker")}) -> result


#  Title                              Content                                                  Site      
#  <chr>                              <chr>                                                    <chr>     
#1 Why Rich People Love Poor Immigra… "Soon after the Immigration Act of 1965 was passed, rea… AmericanT…
#2 California begins giving driver's… "The largest state in  the union began handing out driv… AmericanT…
#3 Immigrants Will Not Fund Our Reti… "Ask Democrats why they support open borders, and they … AmericanT…
```

Comment: I am off to my bed now. If you need further help, please wait.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was of great help. I would need all lines of the same article to be combined, since I will have to use a corpus linguistics approach. I will try to do it myself. If I get any success I let you know. thanks again

Comment: It did not work, I showed the error in the question

Comment: @rll307 I carefully looked into one of the source pages and examined how to scrape text better. I updated my suggestion. Try it and see what happens. I think I am targeting more specific contents this time. I hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you very much. It is working now! It has been of great help!

Comment: @rll307 You are welcome. I should have looked into the source page earlier. Hope you can make progress with your project.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66996370/r-error-in-f-x1l-y1l-scheme-not-supported-in-url-na thanks!